# record app using iOS and Yosemite, but can only see black screen

Tags: osx-yosemite

I am trying to record a video of my app using QuickTime and the new iOS record feature in Yosemite. Problem is all I get is a black screen. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It wasn't able to see video until I switched from my Blue microphone to the iPad's built-in one.

Answer (score 0):

in the QuickTime Player go to > File > New Movie Recording

Click the Arrow (that points down) next to the red Circle

in the Camera choose your iOS device , if it not showing , unplug and plug your iOS device again. if you would like to record the sounds that your iOS makes , change the Microphone as well.

Hope this helps.